# Flutter converting json value to List<List<double>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My value from json : "[[2.1,2.2],[1.0,2.5]]".
How to convert this string to List<List> ?

Comment: If Flutter is converting this to a `List<List<double>>`, then it already *is* a List of Lists.

Answer (score 0):

You start off with a `List<dynamic>` so you can just cast each of its elements to `List<double>`.

```
void main() {
  final decoded = json.decode('[[2.1,2.2],[1.0,2.5]]') as List<dynamic>;
  final listDoubleDouble =
      decoded.map<List<double>>((e) => e.cast<double>()).toList();
  print(listDoubleDouble.runtimeType);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String myJSON = '[[2.1,2.2],[1.0,2.5]]';
var json = jsonDecode(myJSON);
print(json[0][0]);
```